# Android Complex Table Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am new to android and try to construct this layout using TableLayout.

I am not able to set columns for the second row to be column span = 2.

[image]

Comment: @Harsha M V: What have you tried?

Comment: Are you wishing this to fill any size screen?

Comment: @Maximus since am learning. am not gonna use it for production

Comment: @CommonsWare i have tried doing it with linear inside the table. wanted to know if i could span columns and rows

Comment: I see. I was going to post an answer using LinearLayouts, but there would be some conditions with the internal view sizes. The linear layout structure wouldn't be too complicated, but unless the sizes of the view's were exactly same the top cells and bottom cells on the left side may not necessarily line up.

Comment: @Maximus thats exactly wat i am exp. i was wondering like in HTML tables we could span rows.. but as Flavio suggested i guess we cant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can span columns but that's impossible to span rows in TableLayout. Good examples you can find [here](http://coderzheaven.com/index.php/2011/03/android-tablelayout/).